# what's the correct way to wait for qthread termination?

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

I want to know the correct way to create a QThread object, terminate it and wait for the termination in the main thread.

The problem I'm getting is that the wait() method of QThread doesn't return true (as i think it has) and blocks allways until the timeout has expired.

I temporally fixed this by calling quit() method before returning from the run() method in the worker thread, but I think it  shoudn't be the correct way to do that.

In the [QT Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#wait) says that wait() should return true if the thread has finished

> (i.e. when it returns from run())

I'm using QT 5.9 and Linux.

Do anyone had this problem?

**MainWindow.h:**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

# include <QMainWindow>
# include "Worker.h"

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_btnStart_clicked();
    void on_btnStop_clicked();

private:
    Worker *ProcWorker;
    QThread ProcessThread;
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**MainWindow.cpp:**

```
# include "MainWindow.h"
# include "ui_MainWindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent),  ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {
    ui->setupUi(this);

    this->ProcWorker = new Worker ();
    this->ProcWorker->moveToThread(&this->ProcessThread);
    QObject::connect (&this->ProcessThread, SIGNAL(started()), this->ProcWorker, SLOT(RunProcess()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_btnStart_clicked() {
    this->ProcessThread.start ();
}

void MainWindow::on_btnStop_clicked() {
    this->ProcWorker->Terminate ();

    // It blocks until timeout has expired and return false.
    bool ret = this->ProcWorker->thread()->wait (1000000);
}
```

**Worker.h:**

```
#ifndef WORKER_H
#define WORKER_H

# include <QObject>
# include <QThread>

class Worker : public QObject {
Q_OBJECT
private:
    bool TerminateProcess;

public:
    Worker() {
        this->TerminateProcess = false;
    }

    void Terminate () {
        this->TerminateProcess = true;
    }

public slots:
    void RunProcess () {
        while (true) {
            QThread::msleep(100);
            if (this->TerminateProcess) {
                break;
            }

            // Do something
        }

        // I need to add this to get wait() works
        //this->thread()->quit ();
    }
};

#endif
```

Comment: You should subclass the QThead and override the run() function.

Comment: It's another way to implement a thread. I tested it and works ok because in this way there is no event loop. Thanks!

Comment: You can call the static function `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` inside the while loop to process the thread events if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thread does not stop running simply because your `RunProcess` ends. Sending a `quit` is a correct means of shutting down the thread.

That said, you have two other problems related to the threading:

- Your `TerminateProcess` flag is not guaranteed to be seen inside `RunProcess`. You should use a `QAtomicInt` or a `QSemaphore` to ensure the worker thread sees the flag change.
- Your `RunProcess` method blocks the event loop from running and shutting down the thread if you were to call `quit` from the outside (or in `Terminate`). You should either "do something" in the callback from a `QTimer` or use the thread interruption mechanic (`QThread::requestInterruption` from the caller and `QThread::interruptionRequested` inside the loop).

A lot depends on your "Do something" code. If that spends minutes calculating digits of Pi without supporting a means of interruption, no amount of cooperation with the Qt event loop outside of it will save you.

Comment: The [wait()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#wait) specification says that it has to return true when you return from `run()`. Why you say I should call quit before return?

Comment: It's expected that you call `Terminate()` and then`wait ()`. In that case the `TerminateProcess` flag is garanteed to be seen inside `RunProcess`. Maybe `wait()` should be inside `Terminated()` method

Comment: I need a separate thread because I don't want to block the main thread event loop, that's why I don't use a QTimer.  Even using a QTimer inside the working thread will block the event loop of the thread. Blocking the working thread event loop shouldn't  cause any problem because I'm not trying to interact with the thread until it finish

Comment: @Marcelino `run()` here means the method of the Thread object. What `start()` does is roughly "spawn a thread, emit the `started` signal, enter the event loop with `exec`". You connected a function to `started` so that started running, but afterwards the thread just sits spinning in its event loop waiting for signals from outside. You can see this for yourself if you attach a debugger after you called `Terminate`. Had you created a custom `QThread` and put `runProcess` inside `run` like @Tung Le Tanh suggested alsewhere, you would have the desired semantics.

Comment: The example [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details) demonstrates an implementation of the worker pattern you are after. Compare to your own code to figure out what's missing.

Comment: That's ok, I confused `run` method with the `started` signal. I need to call `exit` to stop the event loop of the working thread. Thanks!